# nodejs express routes unable to insert mysql in POST

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, post, routes

I am looking to add code in the database from an express route HTML form.  The form is working, and the Sanitized tracking and office number  is outputted correctly to the console from user input, but the call to the database is not completing.

Any idea why the DB is not being called when the POST is initiated from the express route?

```
npm start
> node-forms@1.0.0 start C:\node-forms
> nodemon src/server.js

[nodemon] 1.14.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option src\server.js:20:14
App running at http://localhost:3000
Sanitized: { trackngNumber: '6e56e77747474747', officeNumber: '5656' }
```

---

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check')
const { matchedData } = require('express-validator/filter')
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "reguser",
  password: '',
  port: 3306
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

router.get('/addtrackingnumber', (req, res) => {
  res.render('addtrackingnumber', {
    data: {},
    errors: {}
  })
})

router.post('/addtrackingnumber', [
  check('trackngNumber')
    .isLength({ min: 13 })
    .withMessage('trackng Number is required')
    .trim(),
  check('officeNumber')
    .isLength({ min:4, max:4  })
    .withMessage('That office Number doesn‘t look right')
    .trim()
], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.render('addtrackingnumber', {
      data: req.body,
      errors: errors.mapped()
    })
  }


  const data = matchedData(req)
  console.log('Sanitized:', data)

  req.flash('success', 'Thanks this has been inputted')
  res.redirect('/')
})

router.get('/trackingnumbers', (req, res) => {
  res.render('trackingnumbers', {
    data: {},
    errors: {}
  })
})

router.post('/trackingnumbers', [
  check('officeNumber')
    .isLength({ min:4, max:4  })
    .withMessage('That office Number doesn‘t look right')
    .trim()
], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.render('trackingnumbers', {
      data: req.body,
      errors: errors.mapped()
    })
  }

  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sqloffice = "INSERT INTO offices (office_Number) VALUES ('1236')";
  var sqltracking = "INSERT INTO `trackingnumbers` (`tracking_Number`, `office_Number`) VALUES ('343434344334', '1236')";
  con.query(sqloffice, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 office inserted");
  });
  con.query(sqltracking, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 tracking inserted");
  });
}); 


  const data = matchedData(req)
  console.log('Sanitized:', data)

  req.flash('success', 'Thanks this has been inputted')


  res.redirect('/')
})


module.exports = router
```

---

addtrackingnumber.ejs

```
<div class="form-header">
  <% if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) { %>
    <h2>Input Fedex Trackng Number</h2>
  <% } else { %>
    <h2 class="errors-heading">Oops, please correct the following:</h2>
    <ul class="errors-list">
      <% Object.values(errors).forEach(error => { %>
        <li><%= error.msg %></li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
  <% } %>
</div>

<form method="post" action="/addtrackingnumber" novalidate>
  <div class="form-field <%= errors.trackngNumber ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' %>">
    <label for="trackngNumber">Trackng Number</label>
    <textarea class="input" id="trackngNumber" name="trackngNumber" rows="4" autofocus><%= data.trackngNumber %></textarea>
    <% if (errors.trackngNumber) { %>
      <div class="error"><%= errors.trackngNumber.msg %></div>
    <% } %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field <%= errors.officeNumber ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' %>">
    <label for="officeNumber">office Number</label>
    <input class="input" id="officeNumber" name="officeNumber" type="officeNumber" value="<%= data.officeNumber %>" />
    <% if (errors.officeNumber) { %>
      <div class="error"><%= errors.officeNumber.msg %></div>
    <% } %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you are also not getting "Connected!" message on your console,this means you aren't connected to db.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why that connection isn't occurring though.